# Postgres JSONB - index on all dynamic (integer) attributes of subobject

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB table in my database that looks like this:

```
             data
-------------------------------
{
  "nestedObject": {
    "dynamic-key-1": 123,
    "dynamic-key-2": 456,
    "dynamic-key-3": 789,
    "and so on": 123
  },
  "rest of object": "goes here"
}
-- a few million more objects come here
```

I'm specifically wondering if it's possible to index on *all* (existing) keys of `data->'nestedObject'` *as integers*. Currently (as I understand it) . I know that if I knew the keys ahead of time, I could just do something like

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_gin_my_jsonb_integer_index ON table 
    USING BTREE (((data->'nestedObject'->>'integerKey')::integer));
```

but unfortunately it's not possible because I don't know the keys ahead of time (attributes of the nested object are generated at runtime based on timestamp etc.). It is possible for many `nestedObject`s to have the same key (ex. many objects may have `data->'nestedObject'->'dynamic-key-1'`), but it is **not** possible for a `nestedObject` to have the same key more than once.

The reason I want to do this is (hopefully obviously) to speed up the queries being run. Specifically, the problematic query is:

```
SELECT tableOne.data AS dataOne, tableTwo.data AS dataTwo FROM tableOne
    JOIN tableTwo ON tableTwo.data->>'someField' = tableOne.id
    WHERE tableOne.data->'nestedObject'->'dynamic-key-goes-here' IS NOT NULL
        AND (tableOne.data->'nestedObject'->>'dynamic-key-goes-here')::integer > 0
    ORDER BY (tableOne.data->'nestedObject'->>'dynamic-key-goes-here')::integer DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

Taking this second query as an example, I can do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on it. I see that it ends up doing a sequential scan (*not* a parallel seq scan) on `((((data -> 'nestedObject'::text) ->> 'dynamic-key-goes-here'::text))::integer > 0)` from `tableOne`, which takes ~75% of the expected query time.

I know that this would be trivial if it was stored "normally," ie. as typical relational data (and this data is relational), but unfortunately 1. I inherited this code from someone else, and 2. I'm not able to do a database migration at this time, so I can't do this.

So given this, is it possible to effectively create an index on this data as integers?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `is not null` test is not necessary, because the `> 0` will also be false if the result was `null` (but removing the check won't change anything regarding the performance - it's essentially just cosmetics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key you are looking for is only present in a (relatively) small number of values, then it might be possible to filter those out using the `?` ("exists) operator. That operator can use an index on a JSONB value.

e.g.:

```
create index on the_table using gin (data  -> 'nestedObject');
```

And use a condition like:

```
where data->'nestedObject' ? 'dynamic-key-1' -- this could use the index if feasible
  and (data->'nestedObject'->> 'dynamic-key-1')::integer > 100
```

However this won't really help if that key is present in the majority of "nestedObjects".

---

If you were looking for one specific value (e.g. dynamic-key = 123) this could be supported using a GIN index and the `@>` operator, e.g. `where data @> '{"nestedObject" : {"dynamic-key-1": 123}}'` but as you are comparing the value using `>` this is really hard to index.

Comment: "If the key you are looking for is only present in a (relatively) small number of values"

Yes! The keys being looked for will only be present in <=1% of all `nestedObject`s, and using a GIN index + the `?` operator cut query time down significantly (~3500ms to <900ms, according to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`). Thank you!